# Cannot increase disk space on VM using GParted

Tags: partitioning, gparted, vmware

I am running VM Workstation 12 Player and have installed Ubuntu 16.10 on the VM.   I would like to resize my partitions to make use of the allocated space and tried to follow the directions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions).  I downloaded gparted-live-0.29.0-1-amd64.iso and booted the VM up with the following settings.

[image]

When I start up.  I get the Ubuntu Unity desktop and click on GParted which is in the Unity menu.  GParted starts up with the following.

[image]

I would like to add the unallocated disk space to /dev/sda1 but cannot move any of the boundaries.  When I click on /dev/sda1 and select Resize, I cannot choose a size greater than 19.455 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove sda2 partition before. It is impossible to resize a partition if there is no unallocated space just next to it. After resizing you can recreate the removed sda2.

Comment: I right-clicked on the sda2 partition and Delete is disabled.  Same when I right clicked on sda5.  Thanks,

Comment: I cannot find, or install lvremove on my Ubuntu system. Thanks,

Comment: /dev/sad5 is not mounted.  Swapoff removed the locks but Delete is still disabled.

Comment: OK.  umount -f did the trick.  It enabled Delet and I deleted sda2 and sda5.  Then I was able to resize sda1 with the unallocated space.